# Linq To SQLite with NHibernate

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate

I use `NHibernate Mapping` and `SQLite` for db.
Part of linq expression works good, but the others like `FirstOrDefault()` or `Take()` doesn't work.
because the `Linq` generated to `select Top(x or 1)`,
and `SQLite` works with `LIMIT`

the config:

`<session-factory name="ScenarioTest">
      <property name="connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="prepare_sql">true</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <property name="format_sql">false</property>
      <property name="generate_statistics">true</property>
      <property name="query.startup_check">false</property>
      <property name="adonet.batch_size">10</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=|DataDirectory|dev.db;Default Lock Timeout=2000000;Version=3;New=True</property>

      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
      <!--<property name="use_outer_join">true</property>-->
      <property name="command_timeout">444</property>
      <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
      <property name="adonet.wrap_result_sets">false</property>
      <property name="default_schema"></property>
      <property name="query.factory_class">NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory, NHibernate</property>
    </session-factory>`

There is a solution?

Comment: Did you configured your session factory to use `SQLiteDialect`? Show us your code

Comment: Yes, I updated the Question

Comment: I can see from the `SQLiteDialect` class that there's support for SQLite's `limit` keyword. I'm unable to see whether it's supported by the LINQ provider though. Have you tried your query as a `QueryOver`-type query?

Comment: I use `Query`, what the diffrenet?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem...
Someone added a new custom dialect to `SQL Server 2008` in the code, and it's override the `SQLiteDialect`.

Thanks.